# Can't read value of "HKLM\...\..." (error2)

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm trying to remove a key value from registry,then I get a error message "Can't read value of "HKLM......"(error 2).

But my program can still run correctly. How could I remove out the error message to make my program look like normal ?

Here is my code, can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
wxRegKey key(wxRegKey::HKLM, "Software\\XXXXX\\XXXX");
wxString keyvaluestr;
key.QueryValue("Path", keyvaluestr);

if(!keyvaluestr.empty()){
    USB_image.LoadFile(_T(""+wxString :: Format ( wxT ( "%s" ) , keyvaluestr ) + "\\image\\USB.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
}else{
    USB_image.LoadFile(wxT("image\\USB.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `wxRegKey::HasValue()` to check for the value existence before querying it.